# For which groups does $ab=cd\implies ba=dc$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I just started studying group theory and I thought of this question which I couldn't solve. I tried making some progress by working on the group of functions of the form $f(x)=ax+b$, $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ where the operation $*$ denotes composition of functions, but to no avail.

Here is the problem: Let the set $X$ be a non-abelian group with respect to some operation $*$. Find all $X$ such that $\forall a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{X}$, $a*b=c*d\implies b*a=d*c$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it's written, there is no such group. You can take $a$ to be the group identity. Then you have
$$ b = cd = dc$$
for all $c$ and $d$ in X. This implies the group is abelian, which is a contradiction.

Comment: So to address your question on a grander scale, when you talk about groups, you define them by their properties usually. This is the notion of "up to isomorphism". So when you say you want to basically, classify, all groups with the given property, you are saying, "What groups have the property _blank_. But that's exactly it, it's just groups with property _blank_. It often won't be something more specific like, "Oh, well, all groups of even order." I would look at the definition of groups via generators and relations to see that sometimes relations are just relations and that's all you get.

Comment: Here's a link to the wiki on generators and relations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group

Comment: Yeah, totally understandable. If you're curious though, google some things on it, or look in some books. It's just another way to talk about groups and can maybe clarify some things. Keep asking good questions!