# Find all groups such that $ab=cd\implies ba=dc$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I just started studying group theory and I thought of this question which I couldn't solve. I tried making some progress by working on the group of functions of the form $f(x)=ax+b$, $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ where the operation $*$ denotes composition of functions, but to no avail.

Here is the problem: Let the set $X$ be a non-abelian group with respect to some operation $*$, and let $e$ be the identity element. Find all $X$ such that $\forall a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{X}$\ $\{e\}$, $a*b=c*d\implies b*a=d*c$.

The question is trivial without the identity condition: [For which groups does $ab=cd\implies ba=dc$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615902/for-which-groups-does-ab-cd-implies-ba-dc/1615913#1615913)

Edit: I repeat, this question is not a duplicate. Please stop voting to close. Thank you

Can a moderator please remove the "This question may already have an answer here" link?

Comment: You can rewrite this as "If $a,b,c,d\neq e$ then $abcd=e\implies badc=1$."

Comment: For any group $X$ and any elements $c$ and $d$ in $X$ let $a=(cd)^2$ and $b=(cd)^{-1}$, then $ba=ab=cd$. Therefore there are no such groups.

Comment: as always, we can let Nex=awesome

Comment: @Nex You should post an answer, possiibly explaining the puchline more explicitly. Because if you don't someone else _will_ post your solution as an answer soon. Trust me...

Comment: Well, what it means is that when $c,d\neq e$ do not commute, then $(cd)^2=e$. @Nex But perhaps you can conclude from there that it is commutative.

Comment: From @Nex argument one has: $ab=cd\implies cd=ba=dc.$ That is, the group is commutative.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  It means that for any $c,d$ we have $ab=ba$, hence $ab=cd$ implies $dc=ab$, so $cd=dc$.

Comment: You can't use $a=(cd)^2$ to conclude $cd=dc$ unless $a=(cd)^2\neq e$. @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Never mind... sorry

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I over looked that possibility, thank you.

Comment: This means we know that for all $c,d$ then either $cd=dc$ or $cd=d^{-1}c^{-1}$.

Comment: In general, when a problem has a trivial solution, just adding a simpleminded condition to "work around" the trivial solution does not make an interesting problem unless the extra condition is for some reason natural.

Comment: @user92570: Even if you hadn't posted the original problem, it would still be obvious that the condition $a,b,c,d\neq 1$ is unnatural and is just there to work around a trivial answer. Look at the answer I just posted: it's all about working around your unnatural extra condition, it's still as uninteresting, only slightly more difficult because I had one hand tied. You could go on and add more conditions to invalidate this answer, and the game could go on forever...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x,y$ be in the group.  From $x(xy) = (xx)y$ we conclude $(xy)x = y(xx)$, that is, $xyx = yx^2$, so $xy = yx$, provided $x\neq 1$, $y\neq 1$, $xy\neq 1$ and $x^2\neq 1$.  Now the three first conditions don't matter, because if $x=1$ or $y=1$ or $xy=1$, we already know $xy=yx$.  So now we have a group in which $xy = yx$ whenever $x^2\neq 1$, or, of course, $y^2\neq 1$ by symmetry, i.e., any two elements one of which is not of order $2$ commute.  Forget the ugly original condition and work with this.

Now consider again any $x,y$.  If either $x$ or $y$ is not of order $2$, they commute, so assume the contrary.  If $xy$ is not of order $2$ then it commutes with $x$, so $x(xy) = (xy)x$, again leading to $xy=yx$.  If $xy$ *is* of order $2$, then $xyxy = 1$, that is, $xy = yx$ since $x$ and $y$ are of order $2$.  So in any case, $xy = yx$.

Comment: Did you mean, "If either $x$ or $y$ is _not_ of order two"?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger: Yes of course, sorry.  Fixed.